# How to capture intel-pt packet on macOS

Tags: macos, cpu, intel

I found there is perf in Linux to capture intel-pt packets.

But, how to capture intel-pt packets on macOS?

I can't find any clues.

Do i have to make a driver for managing intel-pt?